# Python-MySQL connector demo works on WSL but fails when run from Windows

Tags: python, mysql, windows

I have a simple demo program trying to demonstrate the connection to MySQL from Python, that works fine on WSL for fails on Windows.

Here is the sample code

```py
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='mysql-host',
    user='mysql-user',
    password='mysql-password',
    database='myql-db',
    port=3306,
    use_pure=True
)
print(con)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SHOW TABLES;')
for i in cur.fetchall():
    print(i)
```

Output on WSL

```
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7fd6cece4790>
('Table1',)
('Table2',)
('Table3',)
('Table4',)
...
('Table5',)
```

Output on Windows

```
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x00000211CF9B5750>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur = con.cursor()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1410, in cursor     
    raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available
```

It also works on Windows with `mysqlsh.exe`

```
>mysqlsh.exe mysql://mysql-host:3306 -u mysql-user --sql  
MySQL Shell 8.0.33

Copyright (c) 2016, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
Creating a Classic session to 'mysql-user@mysql-host:3306'
Fetching global names for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is 348624462
Server version: 5.6.12 Source distribution
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.
 MySQL  mysql-host:3306  SQL > use mysql-db;
Default schema set to `mysql-db`.
Fetching global names, object names from `mysql-db` for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.
 MySQL  mysql-host:3306  mysql-db SQL > show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql-db   |
+----------------------+
| Table1               |
| ...                  |
+----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.8742 sec)
```

Ping to the `mysql-host` works fine on both. Looking for clues on what else might be wrong?

Comment: the ping works fine with the 3306 port?

Comment: Yes, it works with the port

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a bug, I have reported it and waiting for an update [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111209)

It works everywhere if I do not specify the Database name in the call to the `connect()` function.
But **fails just on Windows if I specify the Database name** in the call to the `connect()` function