# "MySQL Connection not available" error in python flask micro service

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to create a microservice using Python and Flask. The front end created using reactjs and python flask as the microservice. The api request is sent from reactjs and returns the results from the python api. I have created a login function in the app.py to check the user in the database using MySQL and then redirect to a dashboard and it's working. On the dashboard page, there is a page to show the product list, On this page we will connect it to the database using the mysql connector and show the product list but sometimes it does not work and we get the "MySQL Connection not available" from python. What may be the reason for this? The following content is in the app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import mysql.connector
import auth_service
from validate import validate_email_and_password, validate_user
from models import User
import jwt, os
from auth_middleware import token_required
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="user",
   password="pass",
   database="db"
 )

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    cursor = db.cursor()    
    formData = request.json;
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username=%s and password=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (formData['user'],formData['pass'] ))
    data = cursor.fetchone()

    if data is None:
        result = {
            "result": "Invalid login",
          }    
    else:
        result = {
            "result": "Loggedin successfully! Redirecting...",
            "data":data
          }
        
    return result

@app.route('/api/products', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    cursor = db.cursor()    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM products"
    cursor = db.cursor()    
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    if data is None:
        result = {
            "result": "No products found",
          }    
    else:
        result = {
            "result": "Products found",
            "data":data
          }
        
    return result
```

Comment: Check if that answer solves your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664333/4481312

Comment: @marmeladze, thanks for the reply. No, its not working, still getting the same mysql connection error.